# yes,regarding display of toolbox,properties in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

[toolbox is not displaying properly,properties is not being shown any where](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fv1jX.png)
tell me how to restore the original setting in visual studio 2015 **strong text**

Answer (score 0):

Hit F4 or View->Properties Window